# where should I connect to aws from? nodejS server? or angular client?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using nodejs, mongodb, aws-s3 stack for my angular/ionic app. I need to download and store some images such as profile images etc. So I am wondering what is the best practice to connect to aws-S3 from? server or directly client?

For me, it seems a bit more logical to connect directly from client to aws-S3 to download and store images(by thinking it will be faster and strait forward). But I don't wanna install whole aws-sdk package to the app just for this and couldn't find a legit npm package just for S3 client.

So what do you guys think? which one is a better practice?

Edit : I am not using the REST model for connection beetwen the server and the client. Instead using RPC with GRPC. So I connect aws from server that would mean I need to download the each image 2 times to forward it to the client. Firs I need to get it from S3 to server, then send it to client over GRPC and this might be slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) as a proxy between the two (client and S3). Get images' IDs/URLs from your server (since you first have to know which images to get), then, on the client-side, fire an another request, this time towards CF to get those images. Connecting directly to the S3 from the client side infers that you either leave your bucket open to the public (at least for the read permission part) or have access keys stored in plain sight (client-side), which is bad practice altogether.

Comment: I am already sending image metadata to the client, so i know what the image names and where to find them. But the problem is as you said would be to storing access keys in the app.

Answer (score 1):

If it's "public" picture or file you could store it in aws s3 and store the link somewhere in your database. When you want to display the picture you can simply use  for example (So, without sdk).
But If it's private files, you should get them from back office which have an authentication system and can connect to aws with the sdk throw aws athentication.